# ¿Como puedo arreglar este error? FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No existe el fichero o el directorio: 'S.gpg-agent.extra'

Tags: linux, gpg

mi problema es que, al intentar agregar algún PPA en mi Deepin me sale el error de:

**`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No existe el fichero o el directorio: 'S.gpg-agent.extra'`**

Tengo que aclarar que soy nuevo en linux y no se mucho, por lo cual esto tal vez es algo muy fácil de arreglar, pero ya he buscado y no he encontrado nada, si nadie sabe como arreglarlo gracias igualmente.

Comment: Por lo que he leido, lo que estes intentando instalar no es compatible con Deepin. Los PPA no se pueden instalar en cualquier Sistema Operatiovo linux.

Comment: Ah ok, no lo sabia, muchas gracias por la info :D